# Complex Entity Framework linked-graphs issue: how to limit change set / break the graph?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have an EDMX containing `Sentences`, and `Words`, say and a `Sentence` contains three `Words`, say.  Appropriate FK relationships exist between the tables.

I create some words: `Word word1 = new Word(); Word word2 = ...`

I build a Sentence:  `Sentence x = new Sentence (word1, word2, word3);`

I build another Sentence: `Sentence y = new Sentence (word1, word4, word5);`

I try to save `x` to the database, but EF builds a change set that includes everything, including `y`, `word4` and `word5` that aren't ready to save to the database.  When SaveChanges() happens it throws an exception: *Unable to determine the principal end of the ... relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.*

I think it does this because `Word` has an `EntityCollection<Sentence>` on it from the FK relationship between the two tables, and thus Sentence `y` is inextricably linked to Sentence `x` through `word1`.

So I remove the Navigation Property `Sentences` from `Word` and try again.  It still tries to put the entire graph into the change set.

What suggestions do the Entity Framework experts have for ways to break this connection.  Essentially what I want is a one-way mapping from `Sentence` to `Word`; I don't want an `EntityCollection<Sentence>` on Word and I don't want the object graph to get intertwined like this.

**Code sample:**
This puts two sentences into the database because Verb1 links them and EF explores the entire graph of existing objects and added objects when you do Add/SaveChanges.

```
    Word subject1 = new Word(){ Text = "Subject1"};
    Word subject2 = new Word(){ Text = "Subject2"};
    Word verb1 = new Word(){ Text = "Verb11"};
    Word object1 = new Word(){ Text = "Object1"};
    Word object2 = new Word(){ Text = "Object2"};


    Sentence s1 = new Sentence(){Subject = subject1, Verb=verb1, Object=object1};
    Sentence s2 = new Sentence(){Subject=subject2, Verb=verb1, Object=object2};

    context.AddToSentences(s1);
    context.SaveChanges();

    foreach (var s in context.Sentences)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.Subject + " " + s.Verb + " " + s.Object);
    }
```

Comment: I must be missing something. You have a FK constraint between `Sentence` (or its detail) and `Word`. How can the database except a `Sentence` with `Word`s you have not saved yet? It seems to me the constraint should not allow this.

Comment: @Craig, EF will happily add all of the related Words to the database when I save the first Sentence, but it will go one step further and add unrelated sentences too that I didn't want to save yet.  FK was intended to ensure the sentence contain real words and no word is orphaned in database if all the sentences referring to it are gone.

Comment: The changes are supposed to be a unit of work. Do the other sentences in a different context.

Comment: Any suggestions for how to do that in the above example? s2 is never explicitly added to a context, it might even be just a temporary value used while constructing s1, but EF still sucks it in and adds it.  Perhaps manipulate DTO's for all construction work and real entities only for the save step??  Perhaps store the words separately within a Sentence until it's saved and then copy them in? Is there no way to use the same class but keep s2 from attaching itself somehow or to limit the over eager graph building?

Comment: Newing up a new `Sentence` won't add it to a context. Only calling `AddObject` or associating it with something already in a context will add it. But yes, I'd prefer to set things up with DTOs (or, probably preferably, business types) than to use entities to do anything other than represent data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative that does seem to work is to rename and hide the database generated properties (e.g. SubjectP), maintain a separate private copy of the Word that is set, and then fix it up during save:

in Sentence:

```
    private Word subject;
    ...

    public Word Subject { get {return this.subject ?? this.SubjectP;} set {this.subject = value; }}

    public void FixSelfUp()
    {
        if (this.subject != null && subject != this.SubjectP) this.SubjectP = this.subject;
    ...
```

And in SaveChanges() ...

```
    var items = this.context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Added | System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
    // now iterate over them, find any Sentences and call to fix them up.
```

This makes the Sentence behave just like it was intended to behave, allows setting and getting of each Word on it and doesn't allow EF to join them all together into one big graph.

But surely there's a better way than this!