# Adding existing entity to navigation property of a different entity

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF4 and I'm running into a problem when I try to do something that looks quite trivial to me.

I have two entities, let's call them A and B. These entities have a many-to-many association between them with a navigation property on A that contains a list of related B entities.

What I want to do is to add existing B entities to a new A entity. When I try to do that, I get an exception:

> AcceptChanges cannot continue because
>   the object's key values conflict with
>   another object in the
>   ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the
>   key values are unique before calling
>   AcceptChanges.

Has anyone run into such a problem?

More info that might be relevant:

- I've created the DB from the model.
- I have a base entity that both A and B entities inherit from.

**Update:** Found a solution - detach the linked entity and re-attach it to the context, then everything goes as planned.

Comment: Have you read this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008582/invalidoperationexception-when-calling-savechanges-in-net-entity-framework

Double checked that PK's and ID props are configured correctly?

Comment: Checked that now. Everything looks OK...

Comment: Might be related to this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777034/complex-entity-framework-linked-graphs-issue-how-to-limit-change-set-break-the

Comment: Can you post some code showing the adding and saving changes steps and the objectcontext around this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today. In my case my table was a view and I had addded a stored procedure for the InsertFunction. Trouble was that I did not confiugre result bindings from my stored procedure. The symptom was that I could add a single entity fine but got an "key values conflict" exception when adding multiple entities.

Once I made the stored procedure return the new ID (key) and then configured the EF's result biding all was fine.

To the end of the stored procedure add something like this:

```
select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as NewWidgetId
```

In the EF config set the result binding:

```
NewWidgetId -> WidgetId : <widget's type>
```

I found this site helpful: [Using Stored Procedures for Insert, Update & Delete in an Entity Data Model](http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/using-stored-procedures-for-insert-update-amp-delete-in-an-entity-data-model/)

Hope this helps

Rob Smyth