# Can SaveChanges() in EF cause unadded objects to be inserted?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, tdd

I have some code that is a result of pretty much my first effort to do TDD for an actual work project.  Attempting to bootstrap, I created an entity model and tests that assert the presence of data records required materialize a report, the first concrete goal I have identitfied.

I thought it was working reasonably well until I found code that looks like it has a bug, and *YET test still passes*.

Here are the snippetts: **The bug (I think) is a missing call to AddObject().**

If anyone has the patience/inclination to look at the whole thing, I pasted it into a [gist](https://gist.github.com/1158596).

Test Code:

```
TestFactory target = new TestFactory(@"data source=biz2\da;initial catalog=DirectAgents;integrated security=True;");
DirectAgentsEntities actual = target.Create();
Assert.IsNotNull(actual);

var advertisers = actual.Advertisers.OrderBy(c => c.Id).ToList();
Advertiser advertiser1 = advertisers.ElementAt(0);
Assert.AreEqual("Advertiser 1", advertiser1.Name);
```

Implementation Code:

```
 public TestFactory(string connectionString)
 {
     this._connectionString = connectionString;
 }

 public DirectAgentsEntities Create()
 {
    CleanUp(this.DirectAgentsEntities);
    AddAdvertiserClients();
    var db = this.DirectAgentsEntities;
    return db;
}
private void AddAdvertiserClients()
{
    var db = this.DirectAgentsEntities;
    Advertiser a;
    a = new Advertiser
    {
        Name = "Advertiser 1",
        Client = db.Clients.First(c => c.Name == "Client 1")
    };
    db.SaveChanges();
}
private DirectAgentsEntities DirectAgentsEntities
{
    get
    {
        string entityConnectionFormat = @"metadata=res://*/Formss.AB2.Model.ABModel.csdl|res://*/Formss.AB2.Model.ABModel.ssdl|res://*/Formss.AB2.Model.ABModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=""{0};multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework""";
        string entityConnectionString = String.Format(entityConnectionFormat, _connectionString);
        return new DirectAgentsEntities(entityConnectionString);
    }
}
private string _connectionString;
```

How can the row get added without a call to AddObject?  Should I look closer at my code for a subtle bug?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777034/complex-entity-framework-linked-graphs-issue-how-to-limit-change-set-break-the it might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are saying that you feel an `AddObject` is needed after creating the `Advertiser`?
If I have misunderstood the question, my apologies.

When you link the `Advertiser` to a `Client`, what is happening in the generated code is that the `Advertiser` is also being added to the `Client.Advertisers` collection at the other side of the relationship.
This gets noted as a change on the `Client` object and saved by the `SaveChanges` call.

Comment: thanks, you understood my question perfectly.  I appreciate your answer.